# Кто подписывается на событие PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такой кусок кода, взятый с ресурса [Клик](http://howtowpf.ru/mvvm-dlya-chaynikov/)

По нему появился вопрос относительно события `PropertyChanged`

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace firstMVVMapp
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Поля
        private int _summa;
        //Свойства
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int Summa
        {
            get { return _summa; }
            set
            {
                if (_summa != value)
                {
                    _summa = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Summa");
                }
            }
        }
        //Команды
        public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
        //реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        //Конструктор
        public ViewModel()
        {
            ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(arg => ClickMethod());
        }
        //Методы
        private void ClickMethod()
        {
            Summa = A + B;
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос состоит в том, что на это событие никто не подписан. И , насколько я понимаю, то оно в методе `OnPropertyChanged` не должно пройти проверку на `null`. Но почему-то оно ее проходит успешно. Ведь по коду нигде нет подписки `+=` на это событие. Почему тогда оно не `null` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На это событие подписываются объекты [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx), когда вы создаете привязки. Попробуйте реализовать это событие явным образом, поставить брейкпойнт в секцию `add` и посмотреть на стектрейс:

```
private event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
private object objectLock = new Object();

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add
    {
        lock (this.objectLock)
        {
            this.propertyChanged += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (this.objectLock)
        {
            this.propertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> в методе OnPropertyChanged не должно пройти проверку на null.

Ответ уже дали, а я просто дополню, что если определить событие PropertyChanged так

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
```

то не надо проверять `PropertyChanged != null`.